# How can I Logout Linkedin Account using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, linkedin-api

This is my logout script for linked in account. But its logged out only my site login details not logged out opened linkedin account. Can you anybody find my issue?

```
<button onclick="javascript:onLoad();">Logout In LinkedIn</button>
```

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
 api_key: mykey
authorize: true
onLoad: onLoad
</script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
         function onLoad() {
           try {
       IN.User.logout();
  } catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
   }
 setTimeout("goToHome()", 100);
 }

    function goToHome() {
 document.location.href = "https://www.linkedin.com/secure/login?session_full_logout=&trk=hb_signout";
 location.href="logout";

  }
 </script>
```

Comment: Where is the php part?

Comment: Now you check my coding.